# Вывод Python скрипта в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Создал файл .py для теста

```
print ("Hello World")
```

Вызываю его в Word press следующим кодом php:

```
<?php
$pyScript = "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/h.py";
exec("/usr/bin/env python3 $pyScript", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Hello World выводится, все ок, но с одним НО...
выводится в таком виде...

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Hello World" }
```

Как сделать, чтобы видеть чистый Hello World?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если хочется общаться с ВП из питоновских скриптов, то используй [Rest API](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/rest)

Comment: Не "строка 11", а "11 символов в массиве".  И да "в ВП" ты его не "вызываешь".  В общем к ВП твоя дыра не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @evtropov13 Потому что в строке "Hello World" 11 символов... [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) предназначен для вывода информации о переменной. Если обратитесь к документации функции [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php) то увидите что если второй парамерт указан, то массив будет заполнен строками вывода программы.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь `echo`:

```
<?php
$pyScript = "/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/h.py";
exec("/usr/bin/env python3 $pyScript", $output);
echo $output[0];
```